# WebRTC - Saving audio stream into file

Tags: javascript, c++, webrtc

I have two WebRTC peers SENDER (Chrome) and RECEIVER (C++ application).

SENDER initiates a WebTRC connection and sends or streams audio data to RECEIVER.

I need to save the resulting audio data (I don't know typically how long this will be but let's say less than 3 minutes) into a file for later processing.

But I am not sure which end I should do this.  Is it better to save audio on the SENDER side and then send it to RECEIVER?  Or is it better to stream audio from SENDER to RECEIVER and save that stream as it comes into a file on the receiving end?

Comment: I would save it in your c++ application as there is no absolute javascript recorder for the web implementations yet. [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) exists, but you will have more options with an rtp dump provided by the webrtc native API.

Comment: Remember that webRTC streams adapt to your network speed, so quality may vary. If you have a normal media stream, you can record that with [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) and then send the wav file it creates to the server.

Comment: @bwtrent - I'm trying do the saving in my C++ application but don't know what WebRTC's rtp dump functions I can use.  Could you point me to the right direction?  Many thanks.

Comment: possibly http://www.webrtc.org/reference/webrtc-internals/voertp_rtcp#TOC-StartRTPDump will help you out.

Comment: Yes that's the function I'm trying to call but I need to call it on VoERTP_RTCP and to do that I'll need to call static VoERTP_RTCP* GetInterface(VoiceEngine* voiceEngine). But I don't know how to get a pointer to VoiceEngine from the peerconnection_client application... Any idea?